# Lightning URL Hacking Not Working

Tags: urlhacking

I have created a new Lightning button on Lead list view - page. When i click on this button, two fields values should per set, one being pick field and another is Checkbox. Below is what i tried and it did not work

```
/lightning/o/Lead/new?defaultFieldValues=
Lead_Type__c = (!URLENCODE(‘Qualified’))
Accepted_Checkbox__c = 'True'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use proper merge field syntax and commas after each field

You have:

```
Lead_Type__c = (!URLENCODE('Qualified')),
Accepted_Checbox__c = 'true'
```

You need:

```
Lead_Type__c = {!URLENCODE('Qualified')},
Accepted_Checbox__c = true
```

from the [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.links_useful_custom_buttons_create_record_dfv.htm&type=5)

```
/lightning/o/Account/new?defaultFieldValues=
    Name={!URLENCODE(Account.Name)},
    OwnerId={!Account.OwnerId},
    AccountNumber={!URLENCODE(Account.AccountNumber)},
    NumberOfEmployees=35000,
    CustomCheckbox__c={!IF(Account.SomeCheckbox__c, true, false)}
```